# Cannot GET / error while using res.render

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, ejs

I dont know what is wrong. I used every browser but I get the same error of Cannot GET /

here is my code-

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));



app.get("/" , function(req,res){
  res.render( "/views/home.ejs");
});


app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: `res.render('home');`  try this

Comment: still the same error

Comment: check your folder structure it should be `views/home.ejs` and `res.render('home')`  works!!

Comment: Could you show us your folder structure? It may help

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing something like this, assuming your file structure is similar to this:

```
/index.js
/views
/views/home.ejs
```

then do this:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res
        .status(200)
        .render('home')
});
```

Comment: why to create double `views` folder?

Comment: Not creating duplicate views folder, I was just declaring it, I didn't know a better way to do it. Just so you know, two directories that exist inside the same directory cannot have the same name.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how your files are organized but try putting two periods in front of /views
like this
`app.get("/" , function(req,res){ res.render( "../views/home.ejs"); });`